# Bind data to java object

Tags: java, json, performance, bind

I am trying to integrate a service in my system. which send the data in

below format

```
id=c100610414&amount=4681&card_currency_code=INR&transaction_ref_no=c1006f9bc12d411
```

I wish to bind it in java bean object in a performance effective manner.
Below is the code I have done so far

```
String[] splitval = val.split("&");

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < splitval.length; i++) {
String[] _split = splitval[i].split("=");
if (_split.length > 1)
    json.put(_split[0].trim(), _split[1].trim());
}
prePaidCardTxnBean = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), CardBean.class);
```

I want to find a way to either improve this code performance or a better way to bind the above string to object.

Comment: and...? any problems?

Comment: belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The code works fine, however I wish to know if it can be improved further as its important for my use case

Comment: Premature optimization is bad. Just make whatever you are making work and see if its within SLAs or performant for the use case its meeting. Given you are working with other services your I/O will be your biggest performance sink in general. Not splitting a string.

Comment: Of course, converting some trivial strings into JSON, just to parse them afterwards, is everything but efficient. You are already looping over all properties and splitting them into name and value, so all you have to do, is to check the names and set the particular property on the target object.

Comment: @Holger after binding the JSON in object I am saving it in database thus wanted a better a to parse that string.